# How to add view in center of view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have view which has 200x200 width and height

```
let pulsator = Pulsator()
pulsator.radius = 240.0
pulsator.numPulse = 5
viewSearchArea.layer.addSublayer(pulsator)
pulsator.start()
```

I want pulsator will be set center of viewSearchArea. 
How could i do this? 
If anyone wants to know what is pulsator here is the [link](https://github.com/shu223/Pulsator)

Comment: Try to set frame according to the main view.

Comment: What is super View of `Pulsator()` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
pulsator.position = CGPoint(viewSearchArea.layer.bounds.midX, viewSearchArea.layer.bounds.midY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your frame like this:

```
       let height:CGFloat = 200.0
        let width:CGFloat = 200.0
        let xPosition = (self.view.frame.size.width/2) - (width/2);
        let yPosition = (self.view.frame.size.height/2) - (height/2);
        let pulsator = UIView()
        pulsator.frame = CGRect.init(x:xPosition , y: yPosition, width: width, height: height)
```

Another option to set center:

```
pulsator.center = self.view.center;
```

Comment: pulsator not a uiview it dosen't have center property

Comment: is it possible to set frame of it?

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the example project:

```
pulsator.position = viewSearchArea.layer.position
```

Try that or this:

```
pulsator.frame = CGRect(x: (viewSearchArea.frame.width/2) - 100, y: (viewSearchArea.frame.height/2) - 100, width: 200, height: 200)
```